# Google Apps Script Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have the following basic code to attempt changing the value of the textarea element. Using standard HTML works fine; however, using Google Apps Script, it will not work. There will be more to the program which will include additional lines via \n so a standard input tag can't be used - this is just the basic piece in which I need to populate text within the element. Does anyone know if this is possible with GAS? Note, only wanting to use the HTML file, not pure GAS JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<base target="_top">
<button id=calc>test</button>
<textarea id=t></textarea>
<script>
document.getElementById("calc").onclick=function(){
document.getElementById("t").value="test";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try calling `console.log(document.getElementById("calc"))`, See if it exists when the function is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you forgot to put "calc" and "t" inside quatation marks like this - "id_of_an_element"

When I used Visual Code to check if it works in pure HTML it fixed it, but in Google Apps Script it didn't

I tested the below code in Google Apps Script and it works, I hope it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<base target="_top">
<button id="calc">test</button>
<textarea id="t">my text area inital value</textarea>

<script>
  document.getElementById("calc").onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("t").value="test";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Meir - I just did some more testing with it and the way GAS is designed, only the textarea id needs to be quoted. It also requires "select" element ids to be quoted. Basically everything except the standard input. I know it's the proper way to write, I just try to save all the bytes I can (even when it's free like Google) and I'm learning my lesson from doing so. Google is forcing it and I'll just have to start coding it properly due to the restrictions. Thanks again!